# Load all script tags from separated file and include to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to find the best solution for calling js and css in my html. By standard I call them in `<head></head>` and in `<body>` bottom... But I have many pages on my web, and I don't want to in all HTML, one by one, add or remove new script.
I don't want to concat all script in one minified file. My idea is to put all `<script>` in the separated HTML file and in every HTML include this HTML in the head. And, next time when I change some script I only need to change in this separated file, not in every one by one. This is an example

allCss.html

```
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Animation-->  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

allScripts.html

```
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(
        $("#loadStyle").load("allCss.html"),
        $("#loadScript").load("allScripts.html"));
</script>
```

And in index.html, pageA.html, pageB.html etc I only add this in head and bottom of body

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-
to-fit=no">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="description" content=""/>
<meta name="keywords" content=""/>
<title>#</title>

<!-- style-->
<div id="loadStyle"></div>

</head>
<body>

<!-- style-->
<div id="loadScript"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is not working, is there any solution how to do this?

P.S: I hope you can understand

Comment: you would need a template processor along with a server side framework as .net or laravel to do so

Comment: Time to look at using a server side programming language and server side includes so you only have to change one header or footer file....or .... convert the whole app to a *"single page application"* that uses a front end javascript framework and routing

Comment: Although there is a way, you could create script tags from js before loading the page.

Comment: Thnx, I know how to do this with fw like Angular or Vue.js, but this is a job I get from the client, old web page and I need to make some changes, there is no interesting from owner to make SPA or something similar. So i try to figure how to make future work easy for me or another dev. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loadStyle").load("allCss.html"),
    $("#loadScript").load("allScripts.html")
});
</script>
```

I think you forgot the .ready(function(){}); part which i just included in the code above

**Extra**

You can't put a div at the head, script,title,meta,style and noscript tags are the commonly allowed tags, the best you can do, is use a script file instead of a html file to add those other script for example write a JavaScript code to loas other scripts and style in a file for example lets say loader.js include the loader.js to every file, so anytime you want to add a new script just open the loader.js file and include the new script, there are several libraries to make this happen easily.    Here is a library https://github.com/dolox/fallback

Comment: thnx, this is writing error when I write for this example

Comment: Also kindly right click on the browser page an click inspect ut should bring up something look for console if it is on Google chrome this will help show you the error if it is syntax error. It make it easier for both you, me and anyone else who wants to help out

Comment: I can put this I bottom of the body, but in <head> I can't put <div id="loadStyle"></div>. You can’t place a div inside the head element and have valid code – only metadata is allowed. I rly thnx for yout help

Comment: You can't put a div at the head, script,title,meta,style and noscript tags are the commonly allowed tags, the best you can do, is use a script file instead of a html file to add those other script for example write a JavaScript code to loas other scripts and style in a file for example lets say loader.js include the loader.js to every file, so anytime you want to add a new script just open the loader.js file and include the new script, there are several libraries to make this happen easily.    Here is a library https://github.com/dolox/fallback

Comment: That's exactly what I need. But I never work with this. Loader.js is the best?

Comment: I only wrote loader.js as the file name you can give to your script file  that loads all your other scripts. It can be arter.js, anything you want i included a link to a possible easy js loader library you can use

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this a little bit more elaborated using arrays

```js
var div = document.getElementById('scripts');
var script = $('<script>').attr('src', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js');
$(div).append(script);

clicked = function(){
  //bootstrap function wich was not imported from html
  $('#myModal').modal('show')
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="scripts"></div>
<button onclick="clicked()">click me</button>


<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with JavaScript. Loading html files via ajax. In this case you need only one script on every page initially.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

the code itself looks like this:

```
w3.includeHTML = function(cb) {
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
    if (file) {
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
          if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
          if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
          elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
          w3.includeHTML(cb);
        }
      }      
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      return;
    }
  }
  if (cb) cb();
};
```